# UPDATE statement only when score > current score

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I'm trying to create an update statement in a query which is executed in PHP. Although I don't have much PHP experience, I tried it.

this is what I have now:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO scores VALUES ('$uid', '$name', '$score') 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'score' = '$score';";
```

how do I create an if-statement in this? I tried this already:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO scores VALUES ('$uid', '$name', '$score') 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'score' = if('$score' > 'score', '$score', 'score');";
```

Comment: https://thewebfellas.com/blog/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql

Comment: *Please* read up on prepared statements and SQL injection. There is no reason for the variables to be inserted directly even if it is nit user supplied data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO scores (uid, name, score)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = (case when VALUES(score) > score THEN VALUES(score) ELSE score END);
```

Notes:

- List all the columns for the `insert`.  This will save you lots of grief over time.
- Learn to use parameters properly.  That's what the `?` are -- parameter place holders.
- `VALUES()` allows you to retrieve the value being inserted.  Handy in general; necessary when you have multiple rows.
- It is tempting to use `GREATEST()`, but that returns `NULL` if either value is `NULL`.